# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large exception when using custom binding

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

I have a WCF web service in which I can send the data. If the size of the data is large this error comes. For small data, this issue is not coming. Following is my server endpoint configuration,

```
   <bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="default" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647" >
         <readerQuotas maxDepth="32767" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="32767" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
    <binding name="PublishConfig" closeTimeout="infinite" sendTimeout="infinite" receiveTimeout="infinite" openTimeout="infinite">
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
         <readerQuotas maxDepth="32767" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="32767" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

This seems that it is able to get the correct Binding Configuration but don't know why it is not using it.I know this question has been asked many time before, but unfortunately none of them resolved my issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below configuration in the config of both client and server solved the problem.

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

The default value of the request limits is 30000000, which is approximately 28.6MB. In my case data was more than 40MB.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to increase the quota for your binding.